# Как удалить вьюшку RecyclerView в андроиде?

Tags: java, android

Как удалить RecyclerView в андроиде? У меня MainActivity состоит из RecyclerView, который дабавляется любым пользователем. А как можно сделать удаление для каждого пользователя только своего объявления?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить ID автора в объявлении. Выводить кнопку удаления только если ID автора и пользователя совпадают.